# Detect if gaming strategy is better

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, ratio

I collect data about a videogame (think about an ego shooter with kills / deaths etc)

Obviously the higher "kills" is and the lower "deaths" is, the better the players result is.

If I track a lot of different games - these values should be normally distributed - right?

So then I want to implement a major change - like using a different weapon or strategy or something like that - , and after some games evaluate, wheter the results are significantly higher, or not.

Can this be done with the student's t-test? Or would you recommend a different test? How can this be done in R? And how many games would be necessary to get a good result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Re:  "these values should be normally distributed - right?"
Not necessarily.

Yes, this can be done in R (easily).

Comparing results with two different weapons would be a two sample t-test. You would be comparing the mean kills with weapon A vs. the mean kills with weapon B.

If the values aren't normally distributed, you can use non-parametric tests.

You could use ANOVA to see if there's a difference in the means of 3 or more groups at the same time. Assumptions need to be met for the results to be valid. For example, you have a dataset with weapon equals A, B, or C, and you have the number of kill. You could use ANOVA to see if the weapon type significantly (statistically) impacts the mean.